# Verficar buttton radio

Tags: jquery

O código abaixo só confere o primeiro input radio alguém sabe corrigir isso para que ele reconheça pelo menos um input radio marcado

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click','#teste',function(){
      if($('#area').is(":checked"))
   {
        alert('marcado');
   }
   else
   {
        alert('n marcado');
      }
      });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="area" id="area" value="vl1">

<input type="radio" name="area" id="area" value="vl2">

<input type="radio" name="area" id="area" value="vl3">

<input type="radio" name="area" id="area" value="vl4">

<button id="teste">TESTE</button>
```

Comment: O atributo `id` define um elemento único na página, por isso apenas o primeiro funciona. Não faz sentido você atribuir o mesmo valor de `id` para vários elementos na página.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para capturar o `radio` `"checked"`:

```
$(document).on('click','#teste',function(){
     checkRadio();
});

function checkRadio() {
    var isChecked = $("input[name=area]:checked").val();
    if (!isChecked) {
        alert('Selecione algum logotipo');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#teste').click(function(){
  var valor = $('input[name=area]:checked').val();
  if (valor != null){
    alert ("Opção selecionada: "+valor);
  }
  else {
    alert ("Selecione uma opção!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="area" value="vl1">

<input type="radio" name="area" value="vl2">

<input type="radio" name="area" value="vl3">

<input type="radio" name="area" value="vl4">

<button id="teste">TESTE</button>
```